# I have a problem in writing csv from MySQL database in spark using java, any help please

Tags: java, mysql, csv, apache-spark

When I give a path to my local machine in spark code it returns an empty directory as shown in the screenshot attached.

*Here is my code:*

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                            .config(conf)
                            .getOrCreate();
        
Dataset<Row> df =spark.read().format("jdbc")
//    .option("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
      .option("url","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila")
      .option("user","root")
      .option("password","mysql")
      .option("dbtable","cars_details")
      .load();

df.show();

df.write()
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.csv.CSVDataSourceV2")
  .save("D:/csvFile.csv");
```

*Here is the screenshot*:
[image]

Comment: Does the Windows account which is used for your application executing have enough permissions for to create/append a file in the volume root folder? In general this is not allowed - test does the file in some subfolder is created with the same code successfully.

Comment: @Akina don't know about the permissions you mentioned, can you please help me in that

Comment: did you try `write`  instead of `write()`

Comment: Yes @Roshan , but it wasn't working

Comment: @ImranUllah How about `df.write.format("csv").save(<path>)`. Did u try any other format ?